# What would be the PIC and FPC on a juniper router?

Tags: router

Say on a mx960 and I was given XE 3/1/2

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Juniper numbering scheme is fpc/pic/port

So you'd have FPC 3, PIC 1, Port 2